# Postgres SQL Date conversion

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a field stored as timestamp without time zone which looks like this 2017-12-26 06:56:54.958. When I convert it like this:

```
to_char(date_field, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mm:ss')
```

I end up with 26/12/2017 06:12:54. Does anybody know why? And if so, is there a way around this. As you can see, 44 minutes are removed from the date giving a time of 06:12 rather than 06:56.

I have tried to convert to UTC and GMT but I have had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
to_char(date_field, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

`MI` is the pattern for minutes. `MM` is for months, and the case is irrelevant.

Comment: Ahhh...I missed that. Thank you!